# Vb.net convert a into Z

Tags: vb.net, variables, textbox, output

Is there another way to turn an 'a' into a 'Z' in the output textbox ??
because i want to make a Encrypting Software.
And i dont want to freeze my application.

In my form i have an Input/Output textbox and 1 button.

I know you can do it with this code:

```
Output.text = Input.text.Replace("a","Z")
```

but is there another way to do this?

Comment: Ehhh - why would `dim a = "Z"` replace a with Z? You'are assigning a value 'Z' to a variable a?

Comment: Sorry i wrote some things in a strange way. but i updated my question.

Comment: I don't understand. You have a working example, there are *many* ways to do this, including the one you wrote. What is your criteria for "an other way to do this?"

Comment: I know there are many ways to do this but i was wondering if there was a Shorter code that the one i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i think that there is not a shorter way but Replacing it like you did in your code.

When you want to run this code with a button click or when form loads or is shown.
Then its smarter to Put it into a Private sub. Or put your Code into a BackgroundWorker.

so you dont have to paste your code everywhere where you want it to run.

```
Private Sub Encrypt()
Dim Text as string = Input.text
Text = Text.replace("a","z")
Text = Text.replace("b","y")
Text = Text.replace("c","x")
Text = Text.replace("d","w")
'etc
end sub
```

And with the background worker just Write this inside the BackgroundWorkerAsync or something like that:

```
Encrypt()
```

You can write it where you want it to run the code.

Comment: I have used your code and it Worked Realy smooth Thanks!